# Xamarin Forms, ZXingBarcodeImageView is blurry

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, zxing, zxing.net

(**Related**) I have found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873997/how-to-fix-an-unclear-qr-code-image-generated-using-zxing-2-1/25875257), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48505790/datamatrix-barcode-format-blurred-in-zxingbarcodeimageview-xamarin-forms), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43508517/xamarin-display-qr-code-in-form) are questions describing a related problem of ZXingBarcodeImageView rendering a blurry QR code in Xamarin Forms - but they have not lead to a solution for my problem.

### The Problem

I am using [ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) to draw and display a QR Code in Xamarin forms, but the QR code it produces is blurry.

[image]

The reason is in the `.xaml` page I am setting the ZXingBarcodeImageView properties `WidthRequest=300` and `HeightRequest=300`. This is stretching the QR code after it is drawn by the ZXing library:

```
<forms:ZXingBarcodeImageView 
            IsVisible="True"
            x:Name="QRCodeView"
            BarcodeFormat="QR_CODE" 
            HeightRequest="300" //Stretching Height
            WidthRequest="300"  //Stretching Width
            BarcodeValue="-1"
         />
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25873997/how-to-fix-an-unclear-qr-code-image-generated-using-zxing-2-1/25875257) question's top answer suggests binding the attributes `Height` and `Width` ahead of time but no matter how I change the parameters in the `BarcodeOptions` array it suggests, the QR code stays the same.

**How do I change to the setup dimensions of the ZXingBarcodeImageView before drawing time to avoid the stretching?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adding the `BarcodeOptions` to the `ZXingBarcodeImageView` in XAML seems to work in my case. The same when binding from code, as suggested in one of your linked solutions, does not work for some reason.

```
<ContentPage .... xmlns:zxcm="clr-namespace:ZXing.Common;assembly=zxing.portable">
<forms:ZXingBarcodeImageView 
        IsVisible="True"
        x:Name="QRCodeView"
        BarcodeFormat="QR_CODE" 
        HeightRequest="300"
        WidthRequest="300"
        BarcodeValue="-1">
        <zx:ZXingBarcodeImageView.BarcodeOptions>
            <zxcm:EncodingOptions Width="300" Height="300" />
        </zx:ZXingBarcodeImageView.BarcodeOptions>
    </forms:ZXingBarcodeImageView>
</ContentPage>
```

A sample project can be found here: https://github.com/jfversluis/Blurry-ZXingBarcodeImageView

Comment: Indeed the rendering looks better now, but still a bit blurry. +1 for an improvement though I had to implement in a different way like this `BarcodeOptions="300,300"`

Comment: ```<zx:ZXingBarcodeImageView.BarcodeOptions>
            <zxcm:EncodingOptions Width="300" Height="300" />
        </zx:ZXingBarcodeImageView.BarcodeOptions>``` My Xamarin doesn't have any idea about these namespaces, am I missing something?

Comment: I just ran into the same problem while creating a sample project :) Add the ZXing.Net.Mobile package to your Android project